# TFTP Timing Out

Tags: linux, networking, python, tftp

I am writing a script to automatically download file from a tftp server. The problem is that I keep getting a timeout error. I am writing this on my windows box but I have tested it from my linux box from the terminal. I timeout in both places.
My coworker can do it no problem from the command line. Does anyone know why he can access it and I cannot!!!???

It is pingable so i Know i can see it

Comment: Can you access that server with a regular TFTP client? In other words, is the problem specific to your script or your machines?

Comment: Are there any ACLs on your network preventing you from accessing using a particular protocol? Windows firewall enabled? Try disabling it. Can you use a TFTP client to access the server rather than just relying on your script?

Comment: Are you certain there are no restrictions, e.g., host-based firewall rules on the TFTP server or an intervening firewall on the network, that would allow access from your coworker's IP address to UDP port 69 on the TFTP server, but not from the IP addresses of your Windows and Linux systems?

Comment: First do this from the command prompt. once you know it works, try doing it by script.  As folks mention above, there is likely an access problem.  It is important to test on the box you will ultimately run on.

Comment: Ok. I have kali in a vm - Cannot do it from terminal. I have turned off all AV and still cannot do it from windows cmd line